# error: broken symbolic link to ../../../Cellar/pgvector/0.4.4/share/postgresql@14/extension/vector.control

Tags: postgresql, vector-database, pgvector

I'm trying to install pgvector, and I run into the following error after I run "make install" after the cloning, and running "make".

I run the following:

```
cd /tmp
git clone --branch v0.4.4 https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector.git
cd pgvector
make
make install # may need sudo
```

I get the following error after "make install":

```
install: /opt/homebrew/share/postgresql@14/extension//vector.control: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 71
```

And upon running ls on the extension directory, I find vector.control, but upon running file vector.control I get the following:

```
vector.control: broken symbolic link to ../../../Cellar/pgvector/0.4.4/share/postgresql@14/extension/vector.control
```

I cannot install pgvector due to this. I tried manually creating the directories but that did not seem to work either.